# Sklearn load digit ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

I am just beginning to learn the sklearn module and faced my first roadblocks. First I created a number recognition logistic regression model and it seem to work fine. But then I decided to test a random image myself, so I used OpenCV module to opened a picture that I randomly select from online (Shown below). The shape of the image is (425,425,3). I turned them into grayScale and threshold it. Then I try to predict it using the model I just created. But I got a "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2." I tried to use resize, reshape function to my image to match the array size but never seem to work, anyone can help me to solve the problem?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 

test_case = cv2.imread('unnamed.jpg')
test_case = cv2.cvtColor(test_case, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, test_case = cv2.threshold(test_case, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)



digits = load_digits()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target, test_size = 0.23, random_state = 2)

#test_case = test_case.reshape(test_case.shape[0], -1)

train = LogisticRegression(dual = False, max_iter = 1000000)
train.fit(x_train, y_train)
nbr = train.predict(np.array([test_case], 'float64'))
```

[image: The image I am reading from]

Answer (score 0):

First, you train your model on the figures from sklearn. Each digit has the form = (64), which means that they are flattened in a row.

Second, you must change the size of your image to 8x8

For example:

```
test_case = cv2.imread('ELXkj.jpg')
test_case = cv2.cvtColor(test_case, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
test_case = cv2.resize(test_case, (8,8))
ret, test_case = cv2.threshold(test_case, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


digits = load_digits()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target, test_size = 0.23, random_state = 2)

train = LogisticRegression(dual = False, max_iter = 1000000)
train.fit(x_train, y_train)
nbr = train.predict(np.array([test_case.flatten()], 'float64'))
```